# DBCC or index maintenance causes SQL memory dump and error "Cannot continue the execution because the session is in the kill state."

Tags: sql-server-2019

During DBCC and Index Maintenance tasks on one of our databases, we consistently receive an error message: Cannot continue the execution because the session is in the kill state, SQL will also generate a memory dump. (sample below).

We have plenty of space available in the database, and in TempDB.

What are some possible causes? We have applied the latest CU for 2019, and also restored this database to a test environment where the same error is generated.

```
Current time is 10:01:44 11/14/22.                                                                               
=====================================================================                                            
       BugCheck Dump                                                                                             
=====================================================================                                            
                                                                                                                 
This file is generated by Microsoft SQL Server                                                                   
version 15.0.4261.1                                                                                              
upon detection of fatal unexpected error. Please return this file,                                               
the query or program that produced the bugcheck, the database and                                                
the error log, and any other pertinent information with a Service Request.                                       
                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                 
Computer type is Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8280 CPU @ 2.70GHz.                                                   
Bios Version is INTEL  - 6040000                                                                                 
PhoenixBIOS 4.0 Release 6.0                                                                                      
8 X64 level 8664, 2 Mhz processor (s).                                                                           
Windows NT 10.0 Build 14393 CSD .                                                                                
                                     
Memory                               
MemoryLoad = 66%                     
Total Physical = 32767 MB            
Available Physical = 10841 MB        
Total Page File = 37631 MB           
Available Page File = 13601 MB       
Total Virtual = 134217727 MB         
Available Virtual = 134033777 MB     
***Stack Dump being sent to D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\LOG\SQLDump0229.txt  
SqlDumpExceptionHandler: Process 57 generated fatal exception c0000005 EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION. SQL Server is 
terminating this process.                                                                                        
* *******************************************************************************                                
*                                                                                                                
* BEGIN STACK DUMP:                                                                                              
*   11/14/22 10:01:44 spid 57                                                                                    
*                                                                                                                
*                                                                                                                
*   Exception Address = 00007FFAAD371D77 Module(sqlmin+00000000000F1D77)                                         
*   Exception Code    = c0000005 EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION                                                      
*   Access Violation occurred reading address 0000000000000000                                                   
* Input Buffer 122 bytes -                                                                                       
*             DBCC CHECKDB('DP_XXX_SAP') WITH PHYSICAL_ONLY                                                   
*                                                                                                                
*                                                                                                                
*  MODULE                          BASE      END       SIZE                                                      
* sqlservr                       00007FF770D80000  00007FF770E1EFFF  0009f000                                    
* ntdll                          00007FFAD0C70000  00007FFAD0E3EFFF  001cf000                                    
* KERNEL32                       00007FFAD03C0000  00007FFAD046CFFF  000ad000                                    
* KERNELBASE                     00007FFACD470000  00007FFACD68DFFF  0021e000                                    
* CRYPT32                        00007FFACD690000  00007FFACD882FFF  001f3000                                    
* ucrtbase                       00007FFACDA10000  00007FFACDB03FFF  000f4000                                    
* MSASN1                         00007FFACD0B0000  00007FFACD0BFFFF  00010000                                    
* ADVAPI32                       00007FFAD0980000  00007FFAD0A25FFF  000a6000                                    
* msvcrt                         00007FFAD00E0000  00007FFAD017DFFF  0009e000                                    
* sechost                        00007FFACE440000  00007FFACE49AFFF  0005b000                                    
* RPCRT4                         00007FFACE580000  00007FFACE69CFFF  0011d000                                    
* ole32                          00007FFAD0470000  00007FFAD05A8FFF  00139000                                    
* combase                        00007FFAD05B0000  00007FFAD0875FFF  002c6000                                    
* bcryptPrimitives               00007FFACD9A0000  00007FFACDA0BFFF  0006c000                                    
* GDI32                          00007FFAD0080000  00007FFAD00B3FFF  00034000                                    
* gdi32full                      00007FFACD1F0000  00007FFACD373FFF  00184000                                    
* USER32                         00007FFACE210000  00007FFACE375FFF  00166000                                    
* win32u                         00007FFACE1F0000  00007FFACE20DFFF  0001e000                                    
* NETAPI32                       00007FFAC32B0000  00007FFAC32C8FFF  00019000                                    
* pdh                            00007FFAC3470000  00007FFAC34BCFFF  0004d000                                    
* SQLOS                          00007FFAB2970000  00007FFAB2977FFF  00008000                                    
* sqlmin                         00007FFAAD280000  00007FFAB02E7FFF  03068000                                    
* sqllang                        00007FFAB02F0000  00007FFAB2922FFF  02633000                                    
* sqlTsEs                        00007FFAAC990000  00007FFAAD25CFFF  008cd000                                    
* sqldk                          00007FFAAC460000  00007FFAAC98DFFF  0052e000                                    
* OLEAUT32                       00007FFACE380000  00007FFACE43FFFF  000c0000                                    
* msvcp_win                      00007FFACD380000  00007FFACD41BFFF  0009c000                                    
* opends60                       00007FFAB2960000  00007FFAB2968FFF  00009000                                    
* qds                            00007FFAAC260000  00007FFAAC38BFFF  0012c000                                    
* svl                            00007FFAB2930000  00007FFAB295CFFF  0002d000                                    
* WS2_32                         00007FFAD01E0000  00007FFAD0249FFF  0006a000                                    
* MSVCP140                       00007FFAC39B0000  00007FFAC3A3CFFF  0008d000                                    
* MPR                            00007FFAC38E0000  00007FFAC38FAFFF  0001b000                                    
* VCRUNTIME140                   00007FFAC3990000  00007FFAC39AAFFF  0001b000                                    
* WININET                        00007FFABFE20000  00007FFAC0201FFF  003e2000                                    
* WINMM                          00007FFACB640000  00007FFACB662FFF  00023000                                    
* Secur32                        00007FFAC3580000  00007FFAC358BFFF  0000c000                                    
* WINHTTP                        00007FFAC6EE0000  00007FFAC6FACFFF  000cd000                                    
* secforwarder                   00007FFAAC240000  00007FFAAC250FFF  00011000                                    
* ODBC32                         00007FFABA710000  00007FFABA7BEFFF  000af000                                    
* VCRUNTIME140_1                 00007FFAC3520000  00007FFAC352BFFF  0000c000                                    
* WINMMBASE                      00007FFACB610000  00007FFACB63AFFF  0002b000                                    
* cfgmgr32                       00007FFACD420000  00007FFACD461FFF  00042000                                    
* DPAPI                          00007FFACC290000  00007FFACC299FFF  0000a000                                    
* ncrypt                         00007FFACCBF0000  00007FFACCC15FFF  00026000                                    
* bcrypt                         00007FFACCFF0000  00007FFACD01AFFF  0002b000                                    
* NTASN1                         00007FFACCBB0000  00007FFACCBEAFFF  0003b000                                    
* NETUTILS                       00007FFACC790000  00007FFACC79CFFF  0000d000                                    
* SSPICLI                        00007FFACCD10000  00007FFACCD3BFFF  0002c000                                    
* SAMCLI                         00007FFAC9970000  00007FFAC9988FFF  00019000                                    
* WINTRUST                       00007FFACD890000  00007FFACD8E4FFF  00055000                                    
* USERENV                        00007FFACC7A0000  00007FFACC7BFFFF  00020000                                    
* AUTHZ                          00007FFACC310000  00007FFACC35AFFF  0004b000                                    
* dhcpcsvc                       00007FFACA030000  00007FFACA049FFF  0001a000                                    
* profapi                        00007FFACD0C0000  00007FFACD0D3FFF  00014000                                    
* NSI                            00007FFAD0AC0000  00007FFAD0AC7FFF  00008000                                    
* LOGONCLI                       00007FFACC7C0000  00007FFACC7FFFFF  00040000                                    
* psapi                          00007FFACE570000  00007FFACE577FFF  00008000                                    
* kernel.appcore                 00007FFACD0E0000  00007FFACD0EEFFF  0000f000                                    
* instapi150                     00007FFAA85A0000  00007FFAA85B3FFF  00014000                                    
* CRYPTSP                        00007FFACCB20000  00007FFACCB36FFF  00017000                                    
* rsaenh                         00007FFACC530000  00007FFACC562FFF  00033000                                    
* CRYPTBASE                      00007FFACCFE0000  00007FFACCFEAFFF  0000b000                                    
* imagehlp                       00007FFAD00C0000  00007FFAD00DBFFF  0001c000                                    
* gpapi                          00007FFACC040000  00007FFACC062FFF  00023000                                    
* wkscli                         00007FFAC9BC0000  00007FFAC9BD7FFF  00018000                                    
* cscapi                         00007FFAA9AC0000  00007FFAA9AD1FFF  00012000                                    
* sqlevn70                       000001A117150000  000001A11748EFFF  0033f000                                    
* CLUSAPI                        00007FFAC0CF0000  00007FFAC0DA8FFF  000b9000                                    
* DNSAPI                         00007FFACC6E0000  00007FFACC781FFF  000a2000                                    
* IPHLPAPI                       00007FFACC6A0000  00007FFACC6D7FFF  00038000                                    
* RESUTILS                       00007FFAC17A0000  00007FFAC1800FFF  00061000                                    
* VERSION                        00007FFAC3A40000  00007FFAC3A49FFF  0000a000                                    
* hkruntime                      00007FFA96C00000  00007FFA96ED2FFF  002d3000                                    
* hkcompile                      00007FFA96840000  00007FFA9697FFFF  00140000                                    
* dbghelp                        00007FFAC32D0000  00007FFAC3461FFF  00192000                                    
* hkengine                       00007FFA96140000  00007FFA96836FFF  006f7000                                    
* SHLWAPI                        00007FFAD0A30000  00007FFAD0A81FFF  00052000                                    
* XmlLite                        00007FFAC56E0000  00007FFAC5715FFF  00036000                                    
* ncryptprov                     00007FFAC34C0000  00007FFAC3513FFF  00054000                                    
* msv1_0                         00007FFACC900000  00007FFACC966FFF  00067000                                    
* NtlmShared                     00007FFACC8F0000  00007FFACC8FBFFF  0000c000                                    
* cryptdll                       00007FFACC9D0000  00007FFACC9E3FFF  00014000                                    
* kerberos                       00007FFACCA20000  00007FFACCB10FFF  000f1000                                    
* schannel                       00007FFACC470000  00007FFACC4E7FFF  00078000                                    
* SECURITY                       000001A7B6100000  000001A7B6102FFF  00003000                                    
* MSCOREE                        00007FFABA680000  00007FFABA6E5FFF  00066000                                    
* mscoreei                       00007FFAB2980000  00007FFAB2A1BFFF  0009c000                                    
* SqlServerSpatial150            00007FFA939A0000  00007FFA93A41FFF  000a2000                                    
* clbcatq                        00007FFACE6A0000  00007FFACE73EFFF  0009f000                                    
* msxml3                         00007FFA930A0000  00007FFA932CBFFF  0022c000                                    
* msoledbsql                     00007FFA92C50000  00007FFA92ED7FFF  00288000                                    
* COMDLG32                       00007FFAD0880000  00007FFAD0979FFF  000fa000                                    
* shcore                         00007FFACD140000  00007FFACD1E7FFF  000a8000                                    
* SHELL32                        00007FFACEB70000  00007FFAD0075FFF  01506000                                    
* windows.storage                00007FFACDB10000  00007FFACE1E5FFF  006d6000                                    
* COMCTL32                       00007FFAC5140000  00007FFAC51EBFFF  000ac000                                    
* powrprof                       00007FFACD0F0000  00007FFACD13BFFF  0004c000                                    
* MSWSOCK                        00007FFACC970000  00007FFACC9CCFFF  0005d000                                    
* MSOLEDBSQLR                    000001A7B8300000  000001A7B8321FFF  00022000                                    
* dhcpcsvc6                      00007FFACA130000  00007FFACA145FFF  00016000                                    
* sqlncli11                      00007FFA93EE0000  00007FFA94232FFF  00353000                                    
* MSVCR100                       0000000060700000  00000000607D1FFF  000d2000                                    
* SQLNCLIR11                     000001A7B8330000  000001A7B8367FFF  00038000                                    
* netbios                        00007FFABEF50000  00007FFABEF5BFFF  0000c000                                    
* sqlnclirda11                   000000005FD90000  00000000600E8FFF  00359000                                    
* SQLNCLIRDAR11                  000001A7B8390000  000001A7B83C7FFF  00038000                                    
* ualapi                         00007FFACA8D0000  00007FFACA8E9FFF  0001a000                                    
* ESENT                          00007FFACA5D0000  00007FFACA8C1FFF  002f2000                                    
* ntmarta                        00007FFACBE10000  00007FFACBE41FFF  00032000                                    
* clr                            00007FFAAB800000  00007FFAAC23AFFF  00a3b000                                    
* MSVCR120_CLR0400               00007FFAAB6D0000  00007FFAAB7C6FFF  000f7000                                    
* mscorlib.ni                    00007FFAA9DE0000  00007FFAAB370FFF  01591000                                    
* SqlAccess                      00007FFA93020000  00007FFA93095FFF  00076000                                    
* clrjit                         00007FFAA9260000  00007FFAA938AFFF  0012b000                                    
* BatchParser                    00007FFA92690000  00007FFA926B9FFF  0002a000                                    
* SRVCLI                         00007FFAC46B0000  00007FFAC46D5FFF  00026000                                    
* ftimport                       0000000000350000  0000000000374FFF  00025000                                    
* MSFTE                          0000000049980000  0000000049D2DFFF  003ae000                                    
* mskeyprotect                   00007FFAA8410000  00007FFAA8424FFF  00015000                                    
* ntdsapi                        00007FFAC2AA0000  00007FFAC2AC8FFF  00029000                                    
* DSPARSE                        00007FFAC9BE0000  00007FFAC9BECFFF  0000d000                                    
* ncryptsslp                     00007FFAA8490000  00007FFAA84B0FFF  00021000                                    
* xpsqlbot                       00007FFAA4100000  00007FFAA4109FFF  0000a000                                    
* xpstar                         00007FFA90800000  00007FFA90871FFF  00072000                                    
* SQLSCM                         00007FFA90C50000  00007FFA90C63FFF  00014000                                    
* xpstar                         000001A95FDA0000  000001A95FDACFFF  0000d000                                    
* cryptnet                       00007FFABFC20000  00007FFABFC4EFFF  0002f000                                    
* odbccp32                       00007FFA906D0000  00007FFA906F3FFF  00024000                                    
* rasadhlp                       00007FFAC7580000  00007FFAC7589FFF  0000a000                                    
* fwpuclnt                       00007FFACA390000  00007FFACA3F9FFF  0006a000                                    
* oledb32                        00007FFA88EF0000  00007FFA88FDCFFF  000ed000                                    
* MSDART                         00007FFA90080000  00007FFA900A5FFF  00026000                                    
* Comctl32                       00007FFABB220000  00007FFABB499FFF  0027a000                                    
* comsvcs                        00007FFAB2B10000  00007FFAB2CACFFF  0019d000                                    
* msdasql                        00007FFA88E30000  00007FFA88EE0FFF  000b1000                                    
* MSDATL3                        00007FFA88E00000  00007FFA88E21FFF  00022000                                    
* MSDASQLR                       000001A7B8470000  000001A7B847FFFF  00010000                                    
* SQLSRV32                       00007FFA88D40000  00007FFA88DF9FFF  000ba000                                    
* xplog70                        00007FFA999A0000  00007FFA999B5FFF  00016000                                    
* xplog70                        000001A7B86C0000  000001A7B86C3FFF  00004000                                    
* msodbcsql17                    00007FFA90A30000  00007FFA90C03FFF  001d4000                                    
* sqlvdi                         00007FFAC4510000  00007FFAC454AFFF  0003b000                                    
* EpMPApi                        00007FFA8F7B0000  00007FFA8F853FFF  000a4000                                    
* EpMPThe                        000000005FC70000  000000005FC7BFFF  0000c000                                    
* DBNETLIB                       00007FFAA3560000  00007FFAA3581FFF  00022000                                    
*                                                                                                                
*     P1Home: 000001BC95119090:  0000000000000000  0000000000000001  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  000001BC
95118620  00000004FFFFFFFF                                                                                       
*     P2Home: 000001BC95118CB0:  000001BC00000002  000001BC95118620  000001BC95118B30  000001BC95118AB0  000001BC
95118CD0  000001BC95118CD0                                                                                       
*     P3Home: 0100000013440000:                                                                                  
*     P4Home: 00007FFAAD28D6A2:  186B8948246B8966  0FC98548704B8B48  4B8B480005821685  866B850FC9854858  4B8B4803
8B48000B  0189480848894808                                                                                       
*     P5Home: 000001BC95118FF0:  000001BC00000001  000001BC95118620  000001BC95118D80  000001AC25D9BE68  000001AC
25D9BF78  0000000000000002                                                                                       
*     P6Home: 000001BC95119740:  000001BC95118CE0  000001A1C4D96A90  0000000000000001  0000000000000000  00000000
00000000  000001BC95119100                                                                                       
* ContextFlags: 000000000010005F:                                                                                
*      MxCsr: 0000000000001FA8:                                                                                  
*      SegCs: 0000000000000033:                                                                                  
*      SegDs: 000000000000002B:                                                                                  
*      SegEs: 000000000000002B:                                                                                  
*      SegFs: 0000000000000053:                                                                                  
*      SegGs: 000000000000002B:                                                                                  
*      SegSs: 000000000000002B:                                                                                  
*     EFlags: 0000000000010246:                                                                                  
*        Rax: 0000000000000000:                                                                                  
*        Rcx: 0000000000000000:                                                                                  
*        Rdx: 0000000000000002:                                                                                  
*        Rbx: 0100000013440000:                                                                                  
*        Rsp: 0000007212DF2490:  0100000013440000  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  000001AF9DD23DD0  000001A4
ABE03D00  0000007212DF0003                                                                                       
*        Rbp: 0000000000000000:                                                                                  
*        Rsi: 0000000000000000:                                                                                  
*        Rdi: 000001B52AFA6EE0:  00007FFAAEF1CD50  000001B52AFA7FE0  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00000000
00000000  0000000000000000                                                                                       
*         R8: 0000000000000000:                                                                                  
*         R9: 0000000000000003:                                                                                  
*        R10: 000001AF9DD22160:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  000001CAC0C32170  000001BE1758A170  21212121
00000001  000001A198032378                                                                                       
*        R11: 0000007212DF1F80:  0000007212DF2090  00007FFAAD372A1B  000001AF9DD23D28  0000000000000002  000001A4
84122380  0000000000000010                                                                                       
*        R12: 0000000000000000:                                                                                  
*        R13: 000001BA67F80460:  00007FFAAEF40E68  000001B302A08048  000001BA67F80190  00007FFAAF69FE78  00007FFA
AF69FE78  000001BC34D30040                                                                                       
*        R14: 000001AF9DD23D10:  00007FFAAEF4AE58  00007FFAAEF5E380  0000007212DF24F0  0100000013440000  0047000F
00000293  000040000018000B                                                                                       
*        R15: 0000000000000000:                                                                                  
*        Rip: 00007FFAAD371D77:  1824948D48078B49  50FFCF8B49000001  8087894824448B08  4C2444B70F000003  66000003
84878966  B70F00000386B789                                                                                       
* *******************************************************************************                                
* -------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                
* Short Stack Dump                                                                                               
00007FFAAD371D77 Module(sqlmin+00000000000F1D77)                                                                 
00007FFAAD35EC9D Module(sqlmin+00000000000DEC9D)                                                                 
00007FFAAD35E90B Module(sqlmin+00000000000DE90B)                                                                 
00007FFAAD35DAE5 Module(sqlmin+00000000000DDAE5)                                                                 
00007FFAAD35F091 Module(sqlmin+00000000000DF091)                                                                 
00007FFAAE883CE7 Module(sqlmin+0000000001603CE7)                                                                 
00007FFAAE8818E3 Module(sqlmin+00000000016018E3)                                                                 
00007FFAAE874D98 Module(sqlmin+00000000015F4D98)                                                                 
00007FFAAE8ED64C Module(sqlmin+000000000166D64C)                                                                 
00007FFAB1391EF0 Module(sqllang+00000000010A1EF0)
```

Comment: Have you tried restoring the DP_XXX_SAP db to another instance and then checking it there?

Comment: yes, as noted in my post i restored it in rest environment also and encountered the same error.